# Take current datetime and make 2 datetime variables? (6AM - 5:59AM)

Tags: php

I'm trying to make an events page and I want to create 2 `datetime` variables. They would take the current time, and create one variable at 06:00 am, and one at 05:59 am.

The issue I'm having though is with the calculations.

If a person is visiting the page on *March 17, 11PM* - then var1 would be *March 17 06:00AM*, and var *2 March 18 05:59AM*.

However if a person is viewing the page on *March 18 01:00 AM*, then var 1 would still be *March 17 06:00AM*, the same goes for var2.

How would I take the below $date variable, and do the calculations for the other 2 variables?

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
```

[image]

Comment: No, the page is for nightclubs - and sometimes people might check at 1 am or 2 am to see what's still open. That's why I don't want the page at 1AM to suddenly show new events for next night when there are some still going on. The two variables are so that my MySQL script knows which data to select depending on the current date and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply query the current hour to see if it's less than 6; if it is, then the start of the current logical day (based on your rules) was yesterday, 6am; otherwise it was today, 6am. Given this, `strtotime` can trivially get you the "start" time and adding a day to that gives you the "end" time.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$currentHour = date('H');
if ($currentHour < 6) {
    // logical day started yesterday
    $start = strtotime('yesterday 06:00');
    $end = strtotime('today 05:59:59');
}
else {
    // logical day started today
    $start = strtotime('today 06:00');
    $end = strtotime('tomorrow 05:59:59');
}

echo "The current logical day started on ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
echo " and it ends on ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! But how can I make that into 2 datetime variables that I would feed into my MySQL database? For example, the variables right now would look like this `2012-03-17 06:00:00` and `2012-03-18 05:59:00`

Comment: `$end = strtotime('today 05:59:59')` and `$end = strtotime('tomorrow 05:59:59')` comes to mind.

Comment: Wouldn't `strtotime('tomorrow 05:59:59')` show March 19 if I were to view this at 1am?

Comment: @pufAmuf: No, because `tomorrow` would be in the `else` branch, which will not be taken until 6am. Please take a moment to read the code.

Comment: Thanks Jon :). Sorry for my question I'm very inexperienced :)

Comment: @pufAmuf: Being inexperienced is not a crime, we 've all been there. You need to pay attention in order to *gain* experience though. Cheers!

Comment: This is a fair answer that should work just fine...in addition, I would also add that you might want to store the dates as UTC timezone unless you are 100% certain that this site will never be used outside of the default timezone. Even then I would still suggest storage as UTC and display in the user's timezone.

Comment: Hey Jon, sorry to interrupt but I was checking the code just in case... and I seem to have run into the problem I mentioned earlier. I set the timezone to where I am (where it's 12:10 AM), and `strtotime('tomorrow 05:59:59');` produces an end date of `2012-03-19 05:59:59`, not today's (march 18) 5:59 date.

Comment: @pufAmuf: I 'm not sure what your code is exactly and why it's not working. I updated the answer, so please check if you have the exact same code or not.

Answer (score 1):

The method for chopping the date up could be improved, but the principle works...

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

  // get adjusted date which subtracts 6 hours
  $date_adjusted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 60 * 60 * 6);

  // chop off the time (so we are always left with the correct date now)
  $date_adjusted_date = preg_split("/ /",$date_adjusted);

  // Add the time element (in this case 6 AM)
  $correct_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_adjusted_date[0]."T06:00:00"));

  // check the result
  echo $correct_date;
?>
```

Comment: Doing manual time arithmetic is always not the best idea, because if you happen to work near a DST change boundary the results will be subtly different (in this case, subtracting 6 times 3600 seconds will be the wrong thing to do if there has just been a change to or from summer time). Why not do the work with built-in functions that are also DST-aware?

Comment: You are correct as usual, your answer is the better way to do it. I voted for you ,~)